Picamera2 + Hi Quality Camera Issues
i'm using Picamera2 with my raspberry Pi5 and I'm having several issues (I'm building a Super8 Film Scanner)
I can't increase fps - it's always around 30-40 fps - shouldn't it possible running the hi quality camera at 90 fps or even higher? I want to run it with the maximum FPS possible.
2nd, I can't disable AWB and Video Stabilization - picam2.set_controls({'AwbEnable': False}) after setting the config didn't work.
Any ideas?
